# ui issue when coming back from presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar, mpmovieplayercontroller

i have a UI issue with iOS when the personal hot spot is on. 
as i come back from a presentMoviePlayerViewController when i press the done button...
the navigation bar of the view controller gets under the hotspot blue internet...

this how i did the code for the movie player:

```
        movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theUrl];
    [movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [movieController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];


    [movieController.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to present in the RootViewController :

```
 AppDelegate *mainDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[mainDelegate.window.rootViewController  presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
```